# Hartl Section 9.1.3: test_unsuccessful_edit fails with error ParameterMissing "user"

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm running through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and have run into a problem I have been unable to troubleshoot. The test for editing users (**users_edit_test.rb**) fails for reasons I don't understand. Since the tutorial is mostly an exercise in copying code, if have checked and double-checked my typing, but I can't find where I messed up. And, more importantly, I want to understand what is going on. Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

The error message (included below) seems to indicate that the test is launching the *edit* method in the users controller (**users_controller.rb**), which in turn launches the private *user_params* method in the same controller. The *user_params* method sets strong parameters that require the *user* parameter, and permit the *name*, *email*, *password*, and *password_confirmation* parameters. The *user* parameter does not exist when the test runs, so it returns the error.

My first question is, "What is the *user* parameter?" The *name*, *email*, *password*, and *password_confirmation* parameters all refer to columns in the **users** database, and there is also an *id* column. But there is no *user* column. The test and the controller both have an *@user* variable. Is that the *user* parameter? That doesn't seem to make sense, as I ought to be able to call the variable whatever I want to, right? I feel like there is something fundamental here that I am not getting, and if I got it, I could troubleshoot this and answer the second question, "What did I screw up/how do I fix this?", myself.

**users_edit_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    #assert_template 'users/edit'
    #patch user_path(@user), user: { name: "", 
    #                                email: "foo@invalid", 
    #                                password: "foo", 
    #                                password_confirmation: "bar" }
    #assert_template 'users/edit'
  end

end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, 
                                   :email, 
                                   :password, 
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end  

end
```

**users.yml**

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

**Test Output**

> Started
>
> ERROR["test_unsuccessful_edit", UsersEditTest, 2015-05-14 00:05:19 +0000]
>   test_unsuccessful_edit#UsersEditTest (1431561919.08s)
>   ActionController::ParameterMissing:
>   ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: user
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:34:in user_params
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:24:in edit
>   test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:10:in block in class:UsersEditTest
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:34:in user_params
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:24:in edit
>   test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:10:in block in class:UsersEditTest
>
> 27/27:
>   [==================================================================]
>   100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00
>
> Finished in 0.69446s 27 tests, 60 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

Answer (score 0):

For starters: you probably should start your test with a `log_in as(@user)` before `get edit_user_path(@user)`.
That is part of the question: the logged in user provides the params-info you are looking for.
The params are sent by the browser, to one of the controller actions. This is probably one of the hard parts when you are starting Rails; you may want to find some info on the request/response cycle in rails, and how they are mapped to the controller actions.
(And by the way, why are your test lines commented out in your question?)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, @Mauddev. I commented out those lines to verify that the error was coming from the 'get edit_user_path(@user)' line, as opposed to the 'patch user_path(@user)' line, which passes that 'user:' block (that's a block, right?) which I could have screwed up. According to the author, the test should work without the 'log_in_as(@user)' command at this point; Hartl specifically doesn't add that command to this test until section 9.2.1. I'll do some research on the request/response cycle and see where it takes me.

Comment: O, okay. 1) That's a hash, not a block , AFAIK.  2) The clearest explanation I ever got about the routing to and from the actions are in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3SuV-A9bak. 3) If you try to edit the user just by clicking in the browser, can you do that? (old school testing ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

You should implement method Update, then there is no errors.

```
 def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```